# SQL Replacement with No-SQL Application - C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Sometimes ago I was looking for a way to run a SQL-Based application on another computers without installing SQL Server. 
It is impossible and at least user should install sql server express edition.

But I found a stackoverflow related question, a user introduce a third party application which simulate Database just like SQL server and it Also supports linq queries.

I searched again and did not find that app. Is anyone know its name? I think it contains a "No SQL" in its name.

Comment: Am, have you tried to use sql compact?

Comment: LiteDB is a good alternative that has built in Linq support. http://www.litedb.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Microsoft SQL Server Compact or SQLLite

Comment: So SQL server compact is meant to be a portable sql database, which doesn't require installing the whole server.   ideal for embedding and desktop applications. That being said, Compact has limitations. I'm afraid your question is too broad and it doesn't have enough details.